# Load the graph from the titan db for a specified depth in a single or efficitent query

Tags: titan

We are using titan db to store the graph infomation. we have cassandra + es as backend storage and index. We are trying to load the graph data to represent the graph in the webui.

This is the approach i am following.

```
    public JSONObject getGraph(long vertexId, final int depth) throws Exception {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray vertices = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray edges = new JSONArray();
            final int currentDepth = 0;

            TitanGraph graph = GraphFactory.getInstance().getGraph();
            TitanTransaction tx = graph.newTransaction();
            try {
                GraphTraversalSource g = tx.traversal();
                Vertex parent = graphDao.getVertex(vertexId);
                loadGraph(g, parent, currentDepth + 1, depth, vertices, edges);
                json.put("vertices", vertices);
                json.put("edges", edges);
                return json;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void loadGraph(final GraphTraversalSource g, final Vertex vertex, final int currentDepth,
                final int maxDepth, final JSONArray vertices, final JSONArray edges) throws Exception {
            vertices.add(toJSONvertex));
            List<Edge> edgeList = g.V(vertex.id()).outE().toList();
            if (edgeList == null || edgeList.size() <= 0) {
                return;
            }
                for (Edge edge : edgeList) {
        Vertex child = edge.inVertex();
                edges.add(Schema.toJSON(vertex, edge, child));
                if (currentDepth < maxDepth) {
                    loadGraph(g, child, currentDepth + 1, maxDepth, vertices, edges);
                }
            }
        }
```

But this is taking a bit lot of time for the depth 3 when we have more number of nodes exist in the tree it is taking about 1 min to load the data.

Please help me are there any better mechanisms to load the graph efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You might see better performance performing your full query across a single traversal execution - e.g., `g.V(vertex.id()).outV().outV().outE()` for depth 3 - but any vertices with very high edge cardinality are going to make this query slow no matter how you execute it.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer by @Benjamin performing one traversal as opposed to many little ones which are constantly expanding will indeed be faster. Titan uses lazy loading so you should take advantage of that.

The next thing I would recommend is to also multithread each of your traversals and writes. Titan actually supports simultaneous writes very nicely. You can achieve this using [Transactions](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/tx.html).